# Why does this user have two SO accounts in his SE profile and only 1 rep?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

I have noticed that the user [user1602612](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1602612/user1602612) answered many questions and has earned various upvotes and badges including meta badges. But still, his reputation is 1! Furthermore his profile shows he is a member for only 3 days! On the [Reputation Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1602612/user1602612?tab=reputation), it is written that *"This user has no reputation changes"*. Why is this so?

As Rob W commented: this user [has two Stack Overflow accounts](https://stackexchange.com/users/45892/user135448?tab=accounts) within a single Stack Exchange account, one being 3 years old, the other only a few days. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09EeJ.png))

Comment: What??? Two accounts on Stack Overflow?? See bottom of http://stackexchange.com/users/45892/user135448?tab=accounts Screenie: http://i.stack.imgur.com/09EeJ.png (one acc is 3 years old, the other one 2 days).

Comment: Can a person have Two accounts on Stack Overflow with same ID?

Comment: Why -1 for my question?? :(

Comment: @blasteralfred Don't worry about meta votes. These just [express opinion](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Or, @Bart, this user somehow erroneously managed to create a new account using the same OpenID and things got messed up?

Comment: @Arjan Who knows. Perhaps.

Comment: @Bart, I've never seen reputation being removed. Sure, rep can be set to 1 (to remove privileges) while being suspended, but then after a suspension all is fine again. And both accounts are active.

Comment: @Arjan Fair enough. Thing is, we can only guess. I don't get the whole point of this question anyway. There's not much point to random guessing (removed my assumption btw. Equally pointless)

Comment: Agreed, the "discussion" tag is indeed useless, @Bart.

Comment: @Bart - It's reporting a probable bug.

Comment: @Arjan Only way reputation can be removed is spam flags - 6 of them together or one from a moderator carry a -100 penalty.

Comment: Sure, @Yannis, but would that hide other reputation? Seems a bug to me (whether or not some bad behaviour caused the two accounts to have been —partially— merged).

Comment: @Arjan Merge gone bad was my first thought also...

Comment: Possibly a timed suspension. The user gets locked at 1 rep in that case: [http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/)

Comment: @RalZarek In the case of a suspension, a small banner will appear on top of the user profile. This user doesn't have such an indication.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A background merge process hit a deadlock here while a backfill for the new review tasks was running the other day.  When we tried to move their suggested edit votes over as part of the merge, it was at odds with that review task backfill.

This affected 6 accounts in total, all of which I just manually fixed.  If you notice any other oddities, please ping me here and I'll take a look.

Comment: this user also has many posts, but a "reputation of 1"; seems related to the above problem, though a bit dated.  http://stackoverflow.com/users/893605/hitesh-patel?tab=reputation

Comment: @donfede - users have a reputation of 1 (and thus no privileges) while suspended, so that's normal.