# Why do some users have two site accounts, each tied to the same network profile?

Tags: support, bug, status-deferred, user-accounts, network-profile

(Please read carefully. This isn't about sock puppets.)

I just noticed that [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10071800/marlene) has two Stack Overflow accounts. Their [other account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10121005/marlene-wallinger) is listed as having the same network account as the former account.

Even more strangely, if you go to their [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/13923356/marlene), you'll see two listings for Stack Overflow, but they both link to the same account, and both are listed as having the same reputation.

By the way, this isn't unique to that user; there are [a total of 63 pairs of duplicate accounts tied to the same network account](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/843107) on Stack Overflow alone. (There were only six at the time I asked this question, but it increased to 15 in early December 2018, 26 in December 2019, 39 in December 2020, and as of December 2021, has ballooned to the current total of 63.) This also isn't unique to Stack Overflow; there are eight pairs of duplicate accounts on Super User, 10 on Server Fault, eight on Meta Stack Exchange, and possibly more pairs on other sites as well.

There was [a past case of a user having three MSE accounts tied to the same network account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309299/meta-se-account-is-shown-3-times-in-account), but that seems to have been due to a user-specific issue, and has since been resolved. Same goes for [this case from 5 years ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/144027/why-does-this-user-have-two-so-accounts-in-his-se-profile-and-only-1-rep?rq=1), and a case of a former staff member who held moderator and association bonus rights on one account but not the other, seen in earlier revisions of this post.

How was it possible for all of those users to create multiple accounts on the same site, and tie them to the same network account? Also, how can they switch between their two accounts? Can they even use the other one?

Comment: Keeping multiple accounts separate has never been particularly well supported. Having said that, this sure does sound like an obscure bug (or just a case of one-off unrelated bugs all coming together in a coincidence kinda thing), especially given the low number of users affected. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Gonna have to dig through the logs on these to see what actually happened.

Comment: @AdamLear Please see edit. It may have a hint as to what to look for.

Comment: I told them not to use the gravity drive. They wouldn't listen.

Comment: I'm sure that my instance was user error related to testing sign up/sign in. It's hard keeping track of all these sock puppets.

Comment: @Adam did you have a chance to dig through the logs, in the 8 months that passed since the bug was reported?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Nope. Given the rarity of this, I gotta be honest - it's fairly low priority. I'm *curious* about what's going on here, but I have more pressing things to work on.

Comment: @AdamLear Considering the sharp rise in this issue occurring, maybe the priority of this issue should be bumped up a little?

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog What sharp rise?

Comment: @AdamLear From six pairs at the time I asked this question, to 15 last December, and then two more as of today (on SO). As well as one new pair each on SU and here on MSE. Could be a bug with the discontinuation of OpenID.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog Eh. That still seems very minor in the grand scheme of things. The original cases predate OpenID work and while that doesn't mean there isn't a bug there somewhere, this honestly doesn't sound super dire to me. (Plus individual cases can be resolved by merging the profiles.)

Comment: I'm personally rather interested in an answer to this question (being one of the people with a duplicate account on SuperUser: https://data.stackexchange.com/superuser/query/985659/duplicate-superuser-accounts)

One thing I noticed is that while my network profile links to the same account twice, the question/answer counts are different between the two entries: https://stackexchange.com/users/7438488/laverya?tab=accounts

I have no idea (yet) how to use account #927945, only #901341.

Comment: @AdamLear Submitting a "merge user profiles" help request is blocked with the message "These profiles are already linked", so I'm not sure how effective of a solution "send the user to support" is.

Comment: @laverya I merged your profiles, and I'll push a quick update to clarify the error message and provide another resolution path there.

Comment: @AdamLear What does the error message say now?

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog "These profiles appear to be already linked. Please select 'Other' from the topic list and describe your situation to our support team."

Comment: Here is a [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062281/users-accountid-duplications) to list all the currently problematic cases.

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog The CreationDate and LastAccessDate fields show, that yes, some of them *used* these accounts simultaneously (i.e. the LastAccessDate of one of their User entities is later than the CreationDate of their other User entity).

Comment: @AdamLear FYI: many of these "dupe users" have the DisplayName `a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae`.

Comment: @peterh which is longer than the 30-character limit the system normally imposes

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog Yes, to me it looks like as an MSSQL problem from this point.

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog Btw, some of these dupe accounts have 7 years between their `CreationDate`s, some of them was created very exactly in the same moment. I think, if it is not a serious DB problem, then the login mechanism may sometimes think, this user has not an account yet, while it has.

Comment: @SonictheBracketedHedgehog Wow! Some of the users seem using their multiple accounts regularly, simultaneously, since years! And, a lot of rep1 users have NULL in the AccountId column, some of them are many years old! The `a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae` DisplayName is very popular in their circles, too!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Revisiting this. I've confirmed this is still an issue with the [SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1062281/users-accountid-duplications) provided in comments, but this isn't particularly high priority given the number of people impacted - it's a strange case. I've put this into our backlog so we can address in the future and will have the team update here once we have more. Adding [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred) for now.